# SQL Server 2016: Does Spatial Index Update When the Spatial Column Changes?

Tags: sql, geospatial, sql-server-2016

Say I have a table in a SQL Server 2016 database with three columns: a latitude, a longitude, and a geography object (that is computed based on latitude and longitude).

Latitude | Longitude | Geography Object

---

42.12345 | 98.193482 | *some geo code*

12.98774 | 98.193482 | *some geo code*

Then, a spatial index is created based on the geography object column.  If the values of the entries in that column change, does the spatial index get updated automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an index on a computed column that is defined with a deterministic, but imprecise, expression if the column is marked PERSISTED. This means that the Database Engine stores the computed values in the table, and updates them when any other columns on which the computed column depends are updated.

In other words: it will get updated as soon as you update one of the source values.